# How can I implement fragment animation?

Tags: android-fragments, animation

I have read the documentation for [the Animate transitions between fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#set-animations) and implemented it into my code. I have seen videos on how to make animations when switching from fragment to another,
but nothing happens.

This is the code in my Main Activity for replacing the fragment by another:

```java
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment)
                           .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out)
                           .commit();
```

I tried to use the addToBackstack() method to see if it has something with the animation, but nothing happens.

The ***fragment*** in the code above is made when I press on a BottomNavigationView item.

Here's the XML content for the animation in and out:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

```xml
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I replaced the fragment first and then I applied
the animation. It has an order:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out)
                        .replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment)
                        .comit()
```